# max count for each partition in count windowing function MySQL

Tags: mysql, window-functions

I am using MySQL 8.0

I have a table that looks like this:

```
id     user_id        item_id              time
1        3111           4423         2020-06-01 01:00:00
2        3111           4423         2020-06-01 02:00:00
3        2971           36           2020-06-01 01:00:00
4        2971           36           2020-06-01 02:00:00
5        2971           36           2020-06-01 03:00:00
6        2971           815          2020-06-01 22:00:00
```

I am trying to partition by user_id, item_id and create a column that counts number of row for that partition.

I've done:

```
select *
     , count(id) over(partition by user_id, item_id order by time) as cnt
  from table
```

This outputs:

```
id     user_id        item_id              time               cnt
1        3111           4423         2020-06-01 01:00:00       1
2        3111           4423         2020-06-01 02:00:00       2
3        2971           36           2020-06-01 01:00:00       1
4        2971           36           2020-06-01 02:00:00       2
5        2971           36           2020-06-01 03:00:00       3
6        2971           815          2020-06-01 22:00:00       1
```

Which is almost what I want, however I want max cnt value for each partition.

Desired output:

```
id     user_id        item_id              time               cnt
1        3111           4423         2020-06-01 01:00:00       2
2        3111           4423         2020-06-01 02:00:00       2
3        2971           36           2020-06-01 01:00:00       3
4        2971           36           2020-06-01 02:00:00       3
5        2971           36           2020-06-01 03:00:00       3
6        2971           815          2020-06-01 22:00:00       1
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

This still outputs same result...

```
SELECT *
     , max(cnt) over(partition by user_id, item_id order by time) as max_cnt
  FROM ( select *
              , count(id) over(partition by user_id, item_id order by time) as cnt
          from table) subtable;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the `ORDER BY` clause from call to `COUNT`:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(id) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, item_id) AS cnt
FROM yourTable;
```

Using `COUNT` in this way will just return the total count of records for each user/item partition, which seems to be what you want here.